# Is it a good idea to imitate the same name of app to gain number of downloads?

Tags: legal, marketing

Is there a way in order to recognize the game app's name and become popular for downloads in order to earn more money? I tried to check a certain name of the game and the search result appeared to have the same name and genre but owned by different authors. If that case, I was thinking if it is a better idea if I took the same name of the app I'm gonna put it but not exactly before publishing it on Google Play. If not, then I might think of a catchy name of the app and promote it to my friends so that it can spread and share to others in order to gain number of downloads for earnings and popularity. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think fraud is ever really *GOOD* :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by good.

Is it ethically good?  No, at least not in my book.  You're cheating people, confusing them, and purposely misleading them by naming your app something similar to their app just to get people to download it by mistake.

Is it good marketing?  No.  People will figure out what you are all about, and avoid your stuff.

Is it good at generating bad reviews from people?  Yes!  Most definitely yes!  Glad I was able to get one yes in there.